# THREE.VSMShadowMap shadow making some line in the shadow material

Tags: three.js, dropshadow, shadow-mapping

`I want to control the shadow so I added THREE.VSMShadowMap. now I can control it using this

**Renderer**

```
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.VSMShadowMap;
```

**Geometry**

```
  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 32, 16 );
  geometry.castShadow = true;
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } ); 
  const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); scene.add( sphere );
  sphere.scale.set(0.1,0.1,0.1);
  sphere.castShadow = true; //default is false
  sphere.receiveShadow = false; //default
```

**Light**

```
  const directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6);
  directionalLight1.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;      
  directionalLight1.shadow.camera.far = 30;
  directionalLight1.shadow.camera.left = -25;
  directionalLight1.shadow.camera.top = 25;
  directionalLight1.shadow.camera.right = 25;
  directionalLight1.shadow.camera.bottom = -25;   
  directionalLight1.shadow.radius = 25;
  directionalLight1.shadow.blurSamples = 25;
  directionalLight1.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
  directionalLight1.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
  directionalLight1.shadow.bias = 0.05;
```

**But it's showing some unwanted shadows on the floor.** [Click and check the image]   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3JJA.jpg)

```
  const Floor = new THREE.Mesh(
  new PlaneBufferGeometry(50, 50),

  new ShadowMaterial({
  color: 0x000000,
  depthWrite: false,
  opacity: 0.5,
  transparent: true,
  })
  );
  Floor.receiveShadow = true;
  Floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
  Floor.position.set(0, -1.5, 0);
  // Floor.position.y = -1.5;
  scene.add(Floor);
```

**I added image also. please anyone help me**

**I am trying to do like this**

go and check here: https://sbcode.net/threejs/soft-shadows/
`

Comment: From the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/shadows/LightShadow): *`.radius : Float` - Setting this to values greater than 1 will blur the edges of the shadow.
High values will cause unwanted banding effects in the shadows - a greater mapSize will allow for a higher value to be used here before these effects become visible.*